# private message is not showing in messages page but with permission user/uid/messages show the messages list

Tags: privatemsg

I am using privatmsg module.

private message is not showing in messages page but with permission of 'showing read all messages', user/uid/messages show the messages list.

I have check the all permission its ok.

```
After some debugging, i found that in privatemsg.pages.inc file

$query = _privatemsg_assemble_query('list', $account, $argument); 
does not return any result.
```

I will be very grateful getting any suggestion..

Please help